# Auto column widths with images inside

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am currently trying to achieve the following type of grid/column but I am not able to.
Some images have bigger width than others so they need to take up more space.

I will have around 30ish images that I will loop through so i can't just put a set width to each column.
I am not sure how to tackle this problem.

I have the following and I want to have 3 per row it is giving me somewhat okey results but not exactly.

https://codepen.io/BlooDyBG/pen/OJVxYEj

```
  <div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">
  <a href="https://ibb.co/CBBLGnp"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/WnnCJcN/Image-2.png" alt="Image-2" 
 border="0"></a>
 </div>
<div class="flex-item">
  <a href="https://imgbb.com/"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/HqdrqQB/Image-3.png" alt="Image-3" border="0"> 
  </a>
    </div>

   <div class="flex-item">
 <a href="https://ibb.co/3d20nnC"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/r0YZVVw/Image-4.png" alt="Image-4" border="0"></a>
 </div>

      <div class="flex-item">
     <a href="https://ibb.co/QHJ4gTP"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/7pSqfZn/Image-5.png" alt="Image-5" border="0"></a>
            </div>

     <div class="flex-item">
    <a href="https://ibb.co/7p6LHFy"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/R6Vd1WH/Image-6.png" alt="Image-6" border="0"></a>
    </div>

  <div class="flex-item">
  <a href="https://imgbb.com/"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/HqdrqQB/Image-3.png" alt="Image-3" border="0"></a>
  </div>

   </div>
```

CSS

```
.flex-container {
display : flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
 padding : 20px;
}

.flex-item {
 flex: 1 1 auto;
 padding : 20px;
 }

 img {
  width : 100%;
  height : 100%;
 }
```

[image: Hello]

Answer (score 0):

The third part of the `flex` shorthand is `flex-basis`, which informs the browser how to treat sizing of the flexible items. In this case, you've set it to `auto` which instructs the browser to use the width of the content to determine the size.

Instead, you should use something like `flex: 1 1 30%` to ensure that all of the items have a consistent size.

---

Alternately, you can create this type of layout with CSS Grid. That would look something like this:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Yes I know,

But the thing is that I dont want to set the width to the columns to fixed.I have some images with big width and others with smaller ones.

Comment: @Pete In that situation you can enforce 3 per row by splitting them up in the markup (i.e. wrap every three in a `div`) and then you can use `flex-basis: auto` to let them each size automatically.